# Проблема постановки запятой при якобы однородных обстоятельствах

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, однородные-члены, авторская-пунктуация, обстоятельство

У нас с другом возник вопрос. Допускается ли запятая между однородными обстоятельствами "грустно" и "одиноко" в этом предложении.

"Был простой зимний вечер, валил снег, и прохожие плыли под окнами, а я сидел дома один за экраном монитора. Ничего нового в Новый год. Уютно, конечно, чай, кофта, флудильня, **но как-то одиноко, и грустно оттого**, что нет праздника - и не будет, и он даже не намечается."

Мой друг утверждает, что поставил запятую перед союзом "и", так как грустно ему просто так, а вот одиноко уже из-за отсутствия праздника. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли ставить запятую таким образом или она тут всё-таки не нужна?

Comment: Вариант правки  https://proza.ru/2023/01/05/870

Answer (score 1, accepted):

О, извините!) Недоразумение: мне показалось, вы спрашивали про то «и», которое в «и не будет». Потому что тут действительно есть проблема: люди часто забывают, что, если оборот обозначен *слева*, его обязательно нужно и **закрыть** *справа*, в том числе и перед тире: оно не из тех знаков, которые поглощают запятую... А между «одиноко» и «грустно» запятая **по правилам грамматики не требуется**: это на самом деле однородные обстоятельства. Но если есть **желание** их разграничить, можно поставить что-то другое: точку с запятой, или многоточие, или тире... Два тире в одной фразе вполне допустимы.

А запятая — знак исключительно структурный, обязанность ещё и передавать эмоции на ней не лежит. Так что выбирайте из более эмоциональных знаков — и не забывайте про упомянутую закрывающую запятую перед тире, которое перед «и не будет»!

Answer (score 0):

Запятая в данном случае не нужна, т.к. перед нами однородные обстоятельства, соединенные одиночным союзом и.
[Знаки препинания при однородных обстоятельствах](https://https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/odnorodnye-obstoyatelstva.html#i-1)

Answer (score -1):

Ставить можно. Основания на выбор: https://mel.fm/gramotnost/gramotny-otvet/5387106-kogda-nuzhno-stavit-zapyatuyu-pered-tire

Comment: Где в приведенной вами ссылке говорится об этом случае? Там говорится о тире и запятой.